# How can I get different action bar names?

Tags: java, android

I can change the name in the action bar with the manifest, but then the action bar title of every activity will change. How can I change only one?

Answer (score 1):

Each `<activity>` can have [an `android:label` attribute](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#label), with the display name of that individual activity. If an `<activity>` element lacks that attribute, Android uses the `android:label` on `<application>`. So, add `android:label` attributes to all of your activities, with each containing your desired display name of the activity:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name="MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/main_activity_display_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="OtherActivity"
        android:label="@string/other_activity_display_name"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your activity code use:

```
setTitle("title");
```